# equations in command prompt

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am very new to batch, and I have this program that is SUPPOSED to take data in then echo the output of the data, but I need help on making a varible from an equation in cmd.  Here is the code to my program.  Could anybody tell me what i am doing wrong here?  Thanks!

```
@echo off
title growth factor y varible tool
set/p yintercept=enter the y intercept
echo %yintercept%
set/p exponent=enter the exponent
echo %exponent%
set/p x=enter x value
echo %x%
cls
echo %yintercept%
echo %exponent%
echo %x%
eq = %yintercept% ( %exponent% ^ %x% )
pause >nul
```

Comment: To correct the code layout, put 4 spaces before each line; you can see what I did in my edit.

Comment: Please see [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help with asking a good question. For help with correct formatting, see [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working sample of your code:

```
@echo off
title Growth factor y varible tool
set /p yin="Enter the y intercept: "
set /p exp="Enter the exponent: "
set /p x="Enter x value: "
pause
cls
echo Y-intercept:   %yin%
echo Exponent:      %exp%
echo X value:       %x%
echo.
set /a pow=1
for /l %%a in (1, 1, %x%) do set /a pow*=exp
set /a eq=yin*pow
echo Equation = %yin% * (%exp%^^%x%)
Echo          = %yin% * %pow%
Echo          = %eq%
pause >nul
```

If you input:

```
Enter the y intercept: 2
Enter the exponent: 3
Enter x value: 4
Press any key to continue . . .
```

It outputs:

```
Y-intercept:   2
Exponent:      3
X value:       4

Equation = 2 * (3^4)
         = 2 * 81
         = 162
```

And as you can see includes a bit of working. You can easily get rid of this by commenting the respective lines.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have not used the `set` command when trying to evaluate `%yintercept% ( %exponent% ^ %x% )`. You need to use `set` with the `/a` switch for arithmetic.

However, it looks like you are trying to evaluate `%exponent%` to the power of `%x%`. There is no operator to do this with the set command. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5253356/does-a-power-to-function-in-batch-files-exist-exponent) for an explanation on how to do this in Batch. Note: in CMD the set command evaluates carat symbol `^` as bitwise exclusive or, and since carat is used as an escape character, you would need to encase this expression in quotation marks, or add a second carat.

Also, The set command does not imply multiplication symbols. So you need to include `*` where you would like multiplication to occur.

Type `set /?` into a command prompt for an explanation on how to use the set command, specifically the section on the `/a` switch.