# decimals in batch script

Tags: batch-file, decimal

```
echo off
cls

mode con: cols=55 lines=15

:MAIN
color 07
cls

set /p num1="Specify first number: "
cls
set /p num2="Specify second number: "
cls

set /a num3=%num1%*%num2%

echo %num3%
pause
```

Say num1 = 30 and num2= .10 then it would only display 0 and not .3 so how do I make it do decimals and how would you display out to 5 decimals places if needed?

Comment: I tried your code and even replaced the entire prompt with SET /A num3=10*0.3 and it produces an error 'missing operator'.  The help help SET says: "Numeric values are decimal numbers, unless prefixed by 0x for hexadecimal numbers, and 0 for octal numbers.".  So I think its whole numbers only?

Comment: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_math.php

Comment: @miltonb I think "decimal" in that sense indicates base 10 numbering system -- so yeah, it seems to imply integers only. :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SET Command - Floating point numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25951196/set-command-floating-point-numbers)

Answer (score 3):

Batch does not support floating point arithmetic. You have to rely on external scripts.

http://www.computing.net/howtos/show/batch-script-floating-point-math/753.html

[Floating point division in a dos batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503888/floating-point-division-in-a-dos-batch)

Answer (score 1):

```
::turn all strings with decimals to integers to perform arithmetic ops
::does not error check for non-numerics or non-numeric formatting
::I check beforehand or it's left as an exercise for the reader
set mynum=12.34
call:str2dec num pos %mynum%
echo str2dec num %num% , pos %pos% for %mynum%
set mynum=12.3
call:str2dec num pos %mynum%
echo str2dec num %num% , pos %pos% for %mynum%
set mynum=12.
call:str2dec num pos %mynum%
echo str2dec num %num% , pos %pos% for %mynum%
set mynum=12
call:str2dec num pos %mynum%
echo str2dec num %num% , pos %pos% for %mynum%
set mynum=.34
call:str2dec num pos %mynum%
echo str2dec num %num% , pos %pos% for %mynum%
GOTO:EOF
:Str2Dec
::Str2Dec(retVal,decPlaces,strIn)
::returns the integer to %1 of strIn, %3, shifted %2 places to the left
::e.g. Str2Dec num pos 12.34 returns num=1234 pos=2
 SET #=%3
 SET lengthInput=0
 SET decpoint=
 SET /A integerVal=0
 SET /A shifted=0
 :lenStr2Dec
 IF DEFINED # (SET #=%#:~1%&SET /A lengthInput+=1&GOTO:lenStr2Dec)
 IF !lengthInput! LSS 2 SET /A integerVal=%3&GOTO:xStr2Dec
 SET numString=%3
 FOR /L %%x IN (1,1,!lengthInput!) DO (
  SET /A startCharIndex=%%x-1
  CALL SET nextChar=%%numString:~!startCharIndex!,1%%
  IF "!nextChar!" == "." (
    SET decpoint=1
  ) ELSE (
    IF DEFINED decpoint SET /A shifted+=1
    SET /A nextNum=!nextChar!
    SET /A integerVal*=10
    SET /A integerVal+=!nextNum!
  )
 )
 :xStr2Dec
 SET "%~1=!integerVal!"
 SET "%~2=!shifted!"
GOTO:EOF
```

Comment: Please add a description of how this solves the users question. Also, please read [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)