# Convert number to different number in batch file

Tags: batch-file, input, numbers, output

This must be very basic but i can't seem to find a way to get this done

my batch script goes like this:

```
@echo off
echo Type In Desired Volume And Press Enter
echo.
echo 0 = 0 %%
echo 1 = 100 %%
echo 0.10 = 10 %%
echo 0.65 = 65 %%
echo.
set /p input=
echo %input% > "C:\SetVol\Source\Volume.txt
```

I want to make it more user friendly by letting the user input a number between `0` and `100` instead of, for example, `0.10` for 10% audio volume. But i still need to output the `0.10` to a textfile if the user enters `10`.

Google appears to longer be my best friend and we cant seem to communicate on this.

If anybody could help me get starter that would be great.

Comment: Floating point numbers are not supported by batch files, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25951196/set-command-floating-point-numbers . Consider using powershell instead

Comment: Nothing is using floating point numbers @Renat, just strings! TommyMaes, what is your end user supposed to be inputting the string before the `=` or the string after the `=`?

Comment: after `set /p input=` the user will right now input 0.10 for 10% audio volume or 0.25 for 25% volume and so on. But i want them to input 25 instead of 0.25. The 0.25 is still needed for a powershell script so i need to convert the user input to that. And i really want to have this conversion done in a batch file.

Comment: If you want them to type in 25 instead of 0.25, then why don't you tell them that? `Set /P "input=Desired Volume [Enter 25 for 25%% or 0.25]>"`

Comment: @Compo then I must not understand your contribution.

Comment: @T3RROR and jeb: thank you for the answers, I will further look in to it when I have the time but looks very promising !

Comment: As I said, that's your problem @TommyMaes. I've used simple English to explain that I've replaced your eight lines, _(four of which are asking the end user to type in a floating point decimal, when you don't want them to do that)_, with one line which does ask for the correct input format!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way is to convert the input number to the requested output format.

One step is to prefix the input with `0.`

```
set /p input=[Enter volume in %%]: 
set "output=0.%input%"
echo %input% > "C:\SetVol\Source\Volume.txt
```

But this would fails for one digit values like `2%`, becomes `0.2` instead of `0.02`.

This can be fixed with prefix each number with `00` and take the last three digits and add a dot between.

```
set /p input=[Enter volume in %%]: 
set "temp=00%input%"
set "output=%temp:~-3,1%.%temp:~-2%"
echo %output% > "C:\SetVol\Source\Volume.txt
```

Comment: ooeh that is neat! Works realy well. Im kind of new to this but i think i understand the code, please correct me if im wrong: `set "output=%temp:~-3,1%.%temp:~-2%"`
first `%temp:~-3` takes the last 3 digets from temp, then `,1` means use the first of the 3 digets you just took from temp. then puts in `%.%` the dot and then `temp:~-2%`  puts in the last 2 digets from temp.

Answer (score 2):

You can use choice in a loop to make a key based 'slider', and then modifiy the variable value to include a `0.` prefix or be `1` using an if condition:

```bat
@Echo off

 set "volume=50"
:Volume
 cls
 Echo( Current volume: %Volume%%% [I]ncrease [D]ecrease [C]ontinue
 For /f "delims=" %%G in ('Choice /N /C:IDC')Do (
  If "%%G"=="I" If not %Volume% GEQ 100 Set /A Volume+=1
  If "%%G"=="D" If not %Volume% LEQ 0 Set /A Volume-=1
  If not "%%G"=="C" Goto :Volume
 )

 IF %volume% Equ 100 ( Set "Volume=1" )Else If %volume% LSS 10 (
  Set "Volume=0.0%Volume%"
 ) Else Set "Volume=0.%Volume%"
:#your script here
```

For NTFS systems, a variant that stores the last set volume in an alternate data stream and reasigns the last value on return:

```bat
@Echo off

 set "volume=50"
 For /f "Usebackq delims=" %%G in ("%~f0:Volume")Do Set "%%G"
:Volume
 cls
 Echo( Current volume: %Volume%%% [I]ncrease [D]ecrease [C]ontinue
 For /f "delims=" %%G in ('Choice /N /C:IDC')Do (
  If "%%G"=="I" If not %Volume% GEQ 100 Set /A Volume+=1
  If "%%G"=="D" If not %Volume% LEQ 0 Set /A Volume-=1
  If not "%%G"=="C" Goto :Volume
 )
 Set Volume >"%~f0:Volume"
 IF %volume% Equ 100 ( Set "Volume=1" )Else If %volume% LSS 10 (
  Set "Volume=0.0%Volume%"
 ) Else Set "Volume=0.%Volume%"
:#your script here
```

**Note:** by using this method of input, invalid input cannot be entered.

Comment: This is very nice as well ! Will not use it in my program right now but im playing around with it for future knowledge :) thnx !

Comment: Ended up using this to later convert it back again:

`set /P vol=<c:\setvol\source\volume.txt`
`set temp2=`
 `)
if %vol% equ 1.00 ( set "temp2=100" ) else if %vol% lss 0.01 (
 set "temp2=0" ) else if %vol% LSS 0.10 (
 set "temp2=%vol:~-1%" ) else if %vol% gtr 0.10 (
 set "temp2=%vol:~-2%" ) else if %vol% equ 0.10 (
 set "temp2=10" )
)`

Answer (score 1):

Figured out a way to use the choice input, if anyone has a more neat or different way to do this please let me know... 291 more lines to edit...

```
@echo off
echo Choose Audio Volume 0-100 %%
:choice
set /P c=
if /I "%c%" EQU "0" goto :0
if /I "%c%" EQU "1" goto :1
if /I "%c%" EQU "2" goto :2
goto :choice

:0
echo 0 > C:\users\%username%\desktop\numbertest.txt
echo You chose %c% %%
pause
exit
:1
echo 0.01 > C:\users\%username%\desktop\numbertest.txt
echo You chose %c% %%
pause
exit
:2
echo 0.02 > C:\users\%username%\desktop\numbertest.txt
echo You chose %c% %%
pause
exit
```