# batch script to subtract correct digits from variables

Tags: sql-server, variables, batch-file

I am trying to figure out how to subtract the correct information ( I need ) from a variable based on a number with a period ( . ) I know how to tell the batch script to give me a certain amount of digits but if the total is more ( or less ) it doesn't give me the information I am needing, Example

on some answers my current script will give me 4.129 which is what I would need ( the numbers before the period and then the 3 digits after that however when the number before the period is 2 digits or more I get this 41.29 and no third digit which I need for my solution.

```
@echo off

set "File2Read=amts.txt"
If Not Exist "%File2Read%" (Goto :Error)

set count=0
set count2=0

rem This will read a file into an array of variables and populate it 

setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%I IN (%File2Read%) do (
  set /a count=count+1
  set amt[!count!]=%%~nI
)

:TList

:: Print list of files

for /l %%I in (1,1,!count!) do (
   echo %%I] !amt[%%I]!
)
echo.

pause

sqlcmd -S .\Paterson -U sa -P pcAmer1ca -d Website -Q "SET NOCOUNT ON select Price from Inventory WHERE ItemNum = '57'" -h-1 -W > tmp.txt

set /P myVar= < tmp.txt

echo %myVar%

set cost=%myVar:~0,5%

echo %cost%

pause

echo !amt[3]!

for /F "delims=" %%i in ('powershell (!amt[3]! / %cost%^)') do set gal=%%i

set sell=%gal:~0,5%

echo Gallons: %sell%          

pause

Exit

::***************************************************
:Error
cls & Color 4C
echo(
echo   The file "%File2Read%" dos not exist !
Pause>nul
exit /b
::***************************************************
```

I can not figure out how to get the results I am looking for any assistance would be much appreciated

See above code for what I have tried

with the present code I get the results mentioned above

Comment: Batch is simply the wrong language for this task.  You need a scripting language, like Python or Powershell, where you have genuine string manipulation and formatting.

Comment: I understand that but I need this to be in a .bat format ( can have embedded powershell / etc ) due to the environment I am working in and the systems I am using ? Is there any way to get the results I am looking for ? I have seen ways of doing something similar but I am only about 4 months in on learning batch scripting

Comment: You know you can just format the string you get from sql to whatever you need? Are you looking for what exactly? A number with 3 decimals?

Comment: @TimRoberts - batch _is_ a scripting language that has string manipulation capabilties; I'd be curious to know what you classify this language as.

Comment: It barely qualifies as a language at all.  It started out as little more than a way to collect commands, and Microsoft has glued on hackery over time to allow some minimal variable manipulation.  It warps your brain.

Comment: @TimRoberts: I don't agree. I invite you to review some interesting and advanced programs written in the Batch file _programming language_. Support applications: [FindRepl program](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4697) an advanced replacement of `findstr` command, or [A multi-level menu system](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3951) with a better help on CMD commands. Do you want more technicall applications? [Arrays, structures and linked lists](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3244),

Comment: [BBCode to HTML translator](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5016) and even an [Intel 80286 assembler](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6281)! Or animated games, like [Tetris](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6812) or its version [in color](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6936&p=46206#p46206), or the very funny [multiplayer version in color of Snake game](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=8606).

Comment: Drawing graphics? [Drawing HTA "canvas" graphics](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6594), [Borland Graphics Interface standard library](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6625) or [Logo's Turtle Graphics](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6653) that include several fractal curves description and examples.

Comment: I don't doubt that it is possible.  That doesn't make it right.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, your `tmp.txt` contains a floating point number (`<one-or-more-digits><dot><one-or-more-digits>`), you can disassemble it into the part before the dot and the part after the dot, add some zeroes to the second part and shorten it to three characters and re-assemble them (to ensure there are always three digits after the dot).

I put this disassembling and assembling into a subroutine to keep the main code clean.

```
@echo off & setlocal

call :format "0.1" var 
echo %var%
call :format "1.234" var
echo %var%
call :format "2.23456" var
echo %var%
call :format "345.6789" var
echo %var% 
goto :of

:format
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=." %%a in ("%~1") do (
  set "post=%%b000"
  set "%2=%%a.!post:~0,3!"
)
goto :eof
```

Output:

```
0.100
1.234
2.234
345.678
```

Comment: this should work but I am looking to fix the variable ( result ) in this part of the code called %sell% ... echo !amt[3]!

for /F "delims=" %%i in ('powershell (!amt[3]! / %cost%^)') do set gal=%%i

set sell=%gal:~0,5%

echo Gallons: %sell% ...

Comment: `call  :format "%gal%" sell`

Comment: OK I will test your solution and thank you for being so kind as to offer your time an exp with providing this help to me

Comment: your solution works excellent again thank you for your time help and assistance. The only issue I have now is for some reason my programs math does not work when I input the value from the bat file ( but that is in the program I am using not the bat file )

Comment: [No worries](https://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers), that's what we are here for. You might want to ask another question for your math problem (remember to use the right tags)

Comment: it's kind of a weird problem actually I am not sure there is a fix for it ... but I will look into it and if I can not solve it myself I will surely make a post asking for some help ... thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Mmm... I am afraid I don't really understand what you want (what *"subtract correct digits"* means?)... Your description is confusing and your (long) posted code don't show the important point: the contents of `tmp.txt` file... Anyway, I think my answer could help you.

In Batch files the `set /A` command manage integer 32-bits numbers that allows to manage decimal numbers up to 9 digits long. You could *split* these 9 digits in integer and fractional parts and perform simple arithmetic operations on they (*fixed point arithmetic* as described at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25951196/set-command-floating-point-numbers/25952386#25952386)) as long as the intermediate results (of multiplication and division, mainly) don't overflow the 9 digits capacity. Here it is:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set /P "decimals=Enter the number of decimals: "
set /A "decimalsP1=decimals+1, ONE=1"
for /L %%i in (1,1,%decimals%) do set "ONE=!ONE!0"
echo Enter numbers with digits at left of decimal point (like 0.25  not .25)

:loop
echo/
set /P "first=Enter first number: "
if errorlevel 1 goto :EOF
set /P "second=Enter second number: "
call :numToFP FPA=%first%
call :numToFP FPB=%second%
set /A "add=FPA+FPB, sub=FPA-FPB, mul=FPA*FPB/ONE, div=FPA*ONE/FPB
call :FPToNum add=%add%
call :FPToNum sub=%sub%
call :FPToNum mul=%mul%
call :FPToNum div=%div%
echo %first% op %second%:  Add = %add%, Sub = %sub%, Mul = %mul%, Div = %div%
goto loop


:numToFP FPvar=num
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=." %%a in ("%~2") do (
   set "frac=%%b%ONE:~1%"
   set "%1=%%a!frac:~0,%decimals%!"
)
:cutZeros
if not defined %1 set "%1=0" & exit /B
if "!%1:~0,1!" equ "0" set "%1=!%1:~1!" & goto cutZeros
exit /B

:FPToNum var=FPnum
set "FP=%~2"
if "!FP:~%decimals%!" equ "" set "FP=%ONE:~1%%FP%" & set "FP=!FP:~-%decimalsP1%!"
set "%1=!FP:~0,-%decimals%!.!FP:~-%decimals%!"
exit /B
```

In this way you don't need (the *slow*) PowerShell in order to perform a simple division. An example:

```
Enter the number of decimals: 3
Enter numbers with digits at left of decimal point (like 0.25  not .25)

Enter first number: 123
Enter second number: 0.456
123 op 0.456:  Add = 123.456, Sub = 122.544, Mul = 56.088, Div = 269.736
```