# Windows batch file, division of two numbers with error trapping for division of 0

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am attempting to write a windows batch file which implements division of two with some error trapping if the second number is 0. If the user enters 55 for either number it is supposed to go to a loop which finds the total amount of all results of calculating each number from 1-100 mod 5, + 3
After the loop ends, its supposed to display average of all results and append them to a txt file.

When I attempt, the division, the screen pops up and goes away. Never reaches the loop if i enter 55. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

```
:FORLOOP
cls
PAUSE

SET COUNTER=0
SET MODNUM=5
SET ADDNUM=3
SET RESULT=0
SET TOTAL=0
SET AVG=0
GOTO LOOP

:LOOP
SET /A COUNTER=COUNTER+1
SET /A "RESULT=((%LOOP% %% %MODNUM%) + %ADDNUM%)"
ECHO %COUNTER% MOD %MODNUM% PLUS %ADDNUM% IS %RESULT%
SET /A "TOTAL=%TOTAL% + %RESULT%"
IF %COUNTER%==100 
GOTO AVG



:AVG
ECHO.
SET /A "AVERAGE=(%TOTAL% / 100)"
ECHO AVERAGE OF RESULTS IS %AVG%
ECHO.
@ECHO AVERAGE OF RESULTS IS %AVG% >> results.txt
GOTO EXITLOOP

:EXITLOOP
PAUSE EXIT /B
```

Comment: Keep in mind that once you make this work, your division results will still be limited to integers.  `cmd` doesn't have any way of handling fractional values, so they are rounded down to the nearest integer.  Try it in a `cmd` window:  `set /a results=3/4`

Comment: The whole number is all I need for this program but for future reference how would I get the decimal value?

Comment: Try here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18689450/decimals-in-batch-script

Answer (score 0):

Without trying it myself, it looks like once you get to :AVG from :LOOP, it then falls into :EXITLOOP, which exits the batch.

Comment: The problem isn't that he gets to exitloop, but that his code errors out before it even reaches that.

Answer (score 0):

You're not setting %loop% before using it.

```
C:\Users\me>SET /A "RESULT=(( % 5) + 3)"
Missing operand.
```

This means that 3 lines later you get a syntax error:

```
IF %LOOP%==100
```

which bombs out because

```
IF ==100
```

is invalid syntax.
Did you mean to use %COUNTER% instead of %LOOP%?
When debugging, remove your 'cls' commands so you can see your errors.
You can also run your script from a cmd.exe window and then the output won't just disappear when the script ends.
If you replace your two instances of %LOOP% with %COUNTER%, and then fix another syntax error where there's a newline between

```
IF %COUNTER%==100
```

and

```
GOTO AVG
```

then at least it finishes without errors. I'll let you determine whether it's working correctly.

Comment: I just realized that I had the variable loop instead of counter, would that be the problem?

Comment: Ok thank you I just changed it, however when I get to the loop and the "Press any key to continue" appears and I pressed enter, it flashed a screen and dissapeared

Comment: And did you also put `IF %COUNTER%==100` and `GOTO AVG` on the same line so you get one line that looks like this: `IF %COUNTER%==100 GOTO AVG`?

Comment: I just did, I am getting an average of 0 tho, its not going through the loop properly,

Answer (score 0):

I would put your logic check for zero ABOVE your logical check for 55. Division by zero is more dangerous than your 55 check. Ensure the data is valid FIRST before doing anything with it.

There also seems to be no way back from :AVG. It just exits the batch file thereafter.

Comment: Since he doesn't divide by the second number when the first or second is 55 that isn't really necessary.

Comment: May not be necessary, but it's good practice to validate the most risky scenarios first. Though, their real problem here really lies in the lack of return from the AVG label.

Comment: No, the return isn't the problem, but the fact that the script is really, really broken. He's setting wrong variables, his loop doesn't work, and has some syntax errors, which I go over in my answer.

Comment: "After the loop ends, its supposed to display average of all results and append them to a txt file.

When I attempt, the division, the screen pops up and goes away. Never reaches the loop if i enter 55. Any help is appreciated, thanks!"

Description of his key issue, which is what people are resolving here. And his KEY issue therefore is the lack of return from the AVG function, as his script execution simply falls out the end without being handled any further.

Comment: **the screen pops up and goes away. Never reaches the loop if i enter 55** There's a pause before the end, and the data get's written to a file, so in normal execution it isn't necesary to return. However, it doesn't even get to the end. Have you tried your own solution? It errors out before even reaching :AVG

Comment: If he enters 55, it enters FORLOOP. From there, LOOP. From there, AVG. From there... goes to end of batch file. There are other syntax errors in there, for sure, yes, that are terminating his execution earlier than expected, but his code isn't written in such a way that it will loop AT ALL. And given that, it's not unreasonable to suggest changing it so that it DOES. His declared issue is that it terminates early. Errors notwithstanding, it's pretty obvious why this is the case given that it's not coded to loop in any reasonable sense. Better to point the way than just give entire solutions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106949/discussion-between-dennis-van-gils-and-manodestra).

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a few things wrong.

First, you're setting a variable called AVERAGE instead of AVG, so the AVG is always going to be 0. Second, you misspelled DIVISION, in your `IF NOT %SECONDNUM%==55 GOTO DIVISON`

Also, as LinuxDisciple mentions in his answer, batch-files are interpreted on a line by line basis, so you can't have your if and goto on two different lines.

Finally, you have some of the logic of the loop wrong. I think you're trying to do this:

```
 @echo off

@ECHO Carlos Deleon >> results.txt
@ECHO %date% %time% >> results.txt


:MAIN
cls

:FIRSTNUM
ECHO.
ECHO ENTER FIRST NUMBER
SET /P FIRSTNUM=Enter a number and press ENTER :
IF %FIRSTNUM%==55 GOTO FORLOOP
GOTO SECONDNUM

:SECONDNUM
ECHO.
ECHO ENTER SECOND NUMBER
SET /P SECONDNUM=Type a different number and press enter :
IF %SECONDNUM%==55 GOTO FORLOOP
IF %SECONDNUM%==0 GOTO ASKAGAIN
IF NOT %SECONDNUM%==55 GOTO DIVISION
IF NOT %SECONDNUM%==0 GOTO DIVISION

:ASKAGAIN
ECHO.
ECHO INVALID ENTRY, CANNOT DIVIDE BY ZERO, ENTER TWO NEW NUMBERS
GOTO FIRSTNUM

:DIVISION
ECHO.
SET /A RESULT=%FIRSTNUM% / %SECONDNUM%
ECHO %FIRSTNUM% divided by %SECONDNUM% is %RESULT%
@ECHO %FIRSTNUM% divided by %SECONDNUM% is %RESULT% >> results.txt
GOTO FIRSTNUM

:FORLOOP
cls
PAUSE

SET COUNTER=0
SET MODNUM=5
SET ADDNUM=3
SET RESULT=0
SET TOTAL=0
SET AVG=0
GOTO LOOP

:LOOP
SET /A COUNTER=COUNTER+1
SET /A "RESULT=((%COUNTER% %% %MODNUM%) + %ADDNUM%)"
ECHO %COUNTER% MOD %MODNUM% PLUS %ADDNUM% IS %RESULT%
SET /A "TOTAL=%TOTAL% + %RESULT%"
IF %COUNTER% lss 100 GOTO LOOP



:AVG
ECHO.
ECHO %TOTAL%
SET /A "AVG=(%TOTAL% / 100)"
ECHO AVERAGE OF RESULTS IS %AVG%
ECHO.
@ECHO AVERAGE OF RESULTS IS %AVG% >> results.txt
GOTO EXITLOOP

:EXITLOOP
PAUSE EXIT /B
```

Note that if lss means that it keeps looping while the COUNTER is less than 100, which is what you're trying, instead of only loops if the COUNTER is already 100