# How do I display a remainder in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I am using Windows 7 and I have the following:

```
set /p param=Please type a number
set /a answer= %param%/2
echo Your answer is %answer%
```

So anything they type in as a number gets divided by 2. However if it is an odd number, it just rounds it down to the whole number. For example if I typed in `7` it will give me `6` because 7/2 is 3.5 right? But it just rounds it down to the whole number instead of leaving a decimal or in this case a `3.5`. Is there a way I can make it display it? Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Floating point division in a dos batch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503888/floating-point-division-in-a-dos-batch)

Comment: I had already seen this and did not understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set /p param=Please type a number
set /a answer= %param%/2
set /a mod=%param%%%2
echo Your answer is %answer%.%mod%
```

EDIT:

```
set /p param=Please type a number
set /a answer= %param%/2
set /a mod=%param%%%2
if %mod% equ 1 set mod=5
echo Your answer is %answer%.%mod%
```

but this will only with division by 2.

For real float point operations you can use MSHTA through command line and jscript function eval:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set /p exp=expression to calculate: 


:: Define simple macros to support JavaScript within batch
set "beginJS=mshta "javascript:close(new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(1).Write(eval("
set "endJS=)));""


:: FOR /F does not need pipe
for /f %%N in (
  '%beginJS% %exp% %endJS%'
) do set result=%%N

echo result=%result%
```

Comment: @GregRogers if this approach is ok for you can accept the answer so both of us will get some points :)

Comment: I shall, but I have to wait because it will not let me in a short time.

Comment: This won't give you the exact answer. For example if you put in 7, your outcome will be 3.1 not 3.5

Comment: @rrriiight.I will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of making that work properly, since technically does doesn't support math with floats.

You might want to use powershell for this. It will be a lot easier.

Comment: It was just what I was looking for. I just needed something to acknowledge that it "was" a decimal not the actual decimal :)