# How to multiply a column in an CSV sheet from a batch file in Windows

Tags: excel, windows, batch-file, cmd

I need to do a simple multiplication in a CSV sheet from a batch file on a Windows 7 machine.

Assume this is my CSV sheet:

[image]

```
COL_A, COL_B, COL_C, COL_D
23,3,0.667,6
24,4,0,7
25,2,3.55,7
26,3,,8
```

I need this output:

[image]

```
COL_A, COL_B, COL_C, COL_D,COL_E
23,3,0.667,6,1.0
24,4,0,7,0
25,2,3.55,7,5.3
26,3,,8,0
```

Formula for Col_E:

[image]

```
COL_E = COL_C * 1.5
```

Comment: Why does it have to be in batch? Batch can't manipulate Excel files (other than CSV, which your sheet is clearly not). Why not just use VBA or inline formulas like you already used?

Comment: @SomethingDark: ok i will save the file as CSV instead of EXCEL. is it possible to manipulate it in CSV file

Comment: @SomethingDark:  i am converting a .blg  in to CSV  in a batch file. i need to perform this calculation while doing this conversion itself.

Comment: You haven't answered my question. Why does it have to be in batch?

Comment: @SomethingDark:I need to do the relog for atleast 100 blg files , so I have created batch file for this conversion. we are getting the files from different server's so I cant merge it in to one file. after that I will open the csv file and will perform this manual calculation all the time. so I thought  after doing the conversion process whether we can do this programmatically in the same batch file itself..

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot help as everything is captured in images and I cannot see them.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard: i could able to see the images in this question

Comment: Not everyone is in an open network, so for me images are unavailable.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard: ok , I  will add it in the question itself as per ur suggestion. I will separate the column values by comma

Comment: @GerhardBarnard: I have edited the question as you requested ;)

Comment: yes it is possible to do that with csv, but it is not going to be easy.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard: Waiting for a positive reply from you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /F "tokens=1-18* delims=," %%A IN (mycsv.csv) DO (
set sum1="%%~C"
set /a cole=!sum1! * 2
echo %%~A,%%~B,%%~C,%%~D,!cole!
) >> output.csv
```

EDIT, fixed the pipe to support all rows and edited for the output to work, there is going to be rounding off issue though as batch does not generally support fractions, so will need to relook this.

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick response.. when I run this program I am getting the following error  "Missing Operand"

Comment: the output.csv file is generating after the "Missing Operand" error in command prompt. when I open the file, the header row is not there. only one row is present from COL_A to COL_D. I need the header row in the output csv file.

Comment: Fifth line should read `set /a cole=!sum1!*2`. No quotes, use delayed expansion. You can also skip the `!`s altogether because the `/a` flag is weird like that. You're also going to want to change `%cole%` to `!cole!`.

Comment: wrote this on my phone, so will fix few things now. However, just realised that this will not work as intended. in batch doing 2 * 1,5 will return 2, it is rounded off.

Comment: after editing , I got the below output in the output.csv file 26,3,,8,,,,0. only the last record is printing rest all other rows are deleted including header.  the value '0' is printed after 3 columns.

Comment: you can try now, but your calculation is still going to be wrong as mentioned that batch by default rounds off the decimals.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard:  I wont get decimal value after multiplying. so no problem with rounding off issue

Comment: but you are multiplying by `1,5` being a decimal value on its own.

Comment: the value on col_C * 1.5 always an integer only. we would not get any decimal value on the result value

Comment: yes, but the problem in batch is that it rounds it to the lowest value. So `10 * 1,5 = 10` in batch

Comment: to do this properly, you would need to use something external, like cscript/wscript of something cooler like `perl` also see [this](https://www.computing.net/howtos/show/batch-script-floating-point-math/753.html)

Comment: but yes, the script as it is now will work for non decimal calculations like 3 * 2 etc.

Comment: now I am getting the header and all the columns as desired. but the multiplication is not happening  . the values inside the brackets () is the desired value                                                                                       COL_A, COL_B, COL_C, COL_D,COL_E

23,3,0.667,6,0(1)

24,4,0,7,0(0)

25,2,3.55,7,3(5.3)

26,3,,8,0(0)

Comment: yes, because **does not support floating point arithmetic** have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503888/floating-point-division-in-a-dos-batch), it uses external script to do the functionality. So you could combine that, with this script and get the desired result.

Comment: In case if I have a blank value in col_c then that particular row in the output file col_d value is placed in col_c and col_d is null and the col_e multiplication is done on col_d value which is wrong

Comment: I checked with integers the multiplication is happening correctly.. thanks a lot for the quick responses.. only one issue as I mentioned in the above comment.. if col_c got null values

Comment: You could do a statement to check for emty columns.

Comment: I am new to this , could you please guide me on empty column statement too. Thanks in advance